# load an imageView when view is loaded

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sdk

I have a subclass of `UIView` and I want to load an image to an `imageView` on that subView when the view is load.

Exactly like the `viewDidLoad` method in the `viewController`.

Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: Could do on `init` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call in method `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect`

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you're looking for. If you're instantiating your subview through storyboarding, you should place this code in the `initWithCoder:` method. It basically creates an `UIImageView` and adds this to the view as soon as you initialize your subview.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)rect {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:rect]) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anImage"];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        [self addSubview:imageView];
    }
    return self;
}
```